# How to create a fixed size file which is initialized with fixed string?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a file with fixed size which is filled with a repetition of string of my choice.

So far I have tried using `dd` to create a file as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=foo_200kb bs=1024 count=200
```

but obviously the file's content will be random. How can I fill the file with a string of my choice?

**Note**:
Accepted answer works fine however for someone using busybox shell(ash)
they can run following command to get similar results

`yes foo | tr -d '\n' | dd of=foo_200kb bs=1024 count=200`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use process substitution:

```
dd if=<(yes foo) of=foo_200kb bs=1024 count=200
```

Comment: exactly want i need but i didn't understand when/how yes would stop ?

Comment: `yes` adds unwanted newlines

Comment: @AnkurTank When the `dd` command is done, it will close the pipe that it is reading from, so the `yes` command will receive a `SIGPIPE` signal, and will terminate

Comment: @choroba If newlines are not desired, they can be removed with `tr` e.g. `<(yes foo | tr -d '\n')`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bash script to do what you need:

```
#! /bin/bash
word=$1
size=$2
length=${#word}
(( remainder = size % length ))
if (( remainder )) ; then
    echo Warning: Truncating the last word >&2
fi

(( repeat = size / length ))
for (( i=0; i < repeat ; i++ )) ; do
    echo -n "$word"
done
echo -n ${word:0:remainder}
```

Call it with `fill.sh bar 204800 > foo`

Answer (score 2):

You can use brace expansion with `printf` and `head`:

```
$ printf '%.0sbar' {1..100000} | head -c 200000 > foo
$ wc -c foo
200000 foo
```

I definitely prefer the `dd` solution though.